# How can I get conditional data with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list which is called stacOverflows which includes 1 item such as IsOk, Number.

StackOverflows

```
[0]   -- IsOk = false;
[0]   -- Number = 5768;
[1]   -- IsOk = true;
[1]   -- Number = 4348;
```

How can I get number value (if there is any IsOk = true) where IsOk = true with LINQ?

Should I use `any`?

Comment: Its not clear what your object structure is here... Do you have a list which include objects that have IsOk and Number properties on them?

Comment: yes it has IsOk and Number

Comment: In that case 0lukasz0 has beaten me to the right answer. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
yourcollection.Where(i => i.IsOk).Select(i => i.Number).ToList()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you expect exact one item, use `Single`:

```
var item = collection.Single(i => i.IsOk).Number;
```

Otherwise, use `Where`/`Select`

```
var items = collection.Where(i => i.IsOk).Select(i => i.Number);
```